# Why does std::atomic<T>::operator= should return a value instead of reference?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic

When using atomic type in c++

Why does std::atomic<T>::operator= should return a value instead of reference?
It's not like other common assignment operator which returns a reference.

From a [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator%3D) site I can get some hint.

> Unlike most assignment operators, the assignment operators for atomic types do not return a reference to their left-hand arguments. They return a copy of the stored value instead.

I can guess that if I use reference, it has a problem of atomic things.
But I'm not completely clear.

Do you have any example for the async error case ?

And if I return a value instead of a reference, why does the async error gone?

Comment: It returns a `T`, not `atomic<T>`. If it returned a reference to a non-atomic type, there would be no point in any of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you have any example for the async error case ?

The return type of that operator is `T`. If it were `T&`, you could do something like:

```
atomic<int> i;
++(i = 10);
```

And the `++` would be a non-atomic read-increment-write, which is very wrong.

> And if I return a value instead of a reference, why does the async error gone?

Since it returns a copy, not a reference, you can't do what I showed above.

Comment: But atomic<int> support ++ operation. If return atomic<int>&, is it possible to increase?

Comment: If it returned `atomic<int>&`, that would be possible.

Comment: Then what is the reason of that atomic type operator= doesn't return atomic<T>& ?

Comment: @myoldgrandpa probably because it would then be difficult to chain assignment with something else, like another assignment or with an `if` or some other kind.

Answer (score 2):

The `operator=` has a return value for allow multiple assignments in a single line:

```
Object a, b;
// Short form
a = b = <value>;
// Equivalent long form
a = <value>;
b = <value>;
```

For accomplish this behavior, on may consider `std::atomic<T>::operator=` to return `T`, `T &` or `std::atomic<T> &`:

- `T`

  This is how the operator is actually implemented.
- `T &`

  Like a pointer, a reference should **point** to **object** of type T.
  But there is **no** T object stored inside an atomic object!

  So, there is nothing suitable for being returned as `T &`.
- `std::atomic<T> &`

  With such return type one **cannot** write

  ```
  std::atomic<uint32_t> a, b;
  a = b = 5;
  ```

  `b = 5` returns the type `std::atomic<T> &`, and one **cannot** assign
  the atomic variable a to that type because corresponded `operator=` is marked as **deleted** (assigning one atomic variable to another is prohibited).

As one can see, the only possible way for allow multiple assignments is returning `T`, as it is actually implemented.

Comment: Like a pointer, a reference should point to object of type T. But there is no T object stored inside an atomic object! => What do you mean? atomic type has its value in it

Comment: Atomic type **behaves** like it has a T value in it. The atomic implementation could even have this value, but it obviously won't give a direct access to it.